# Vuetify Unable to locate target when using attach on v-autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use [autocomplete](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#autocomplete) from Vuetify and I am facing issues there because on my website I have one of the outer divs `position: relative` the dropdown part of the `autocompelete`, which is `position: absolute`, is attaching itself not to the bottom of the `input` but in random place.

Autocomplete has a prop `attach` which `Specifies which DOM element that this component should detach to. Use either a CSS selector string or an object reference to the element.` so I thought I use that and set it to class of my input.

And this works but it causes warning in the console

```
[Vuetify] Unable to locate target v-autocomplete

found in

---> <VMenu>
       <VAutocomplete>
         <VCard>
           <VApp>
             <Root>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/Allan11/pen/eoOZqN) the link where I reproduced the console warning.

Comment: The codepen you linked results in a 404 error...

Answer (score 9):

If you are not using `v-app` component in App.vue, make sure to add `data-app` attribute to the `div` with the id `app` in App.vue.

The result will be like the following:

```
<template>
    <div id="app" data-app>
        ....  All components, routers, views  here ...
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="headline font-weight-regular blue-grey white--text">Profile</v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-subheader class="pa-0">Where do you live?</v-subheader>
        <v-autocomplete
          v-model="model"
          :hint="!isEditing ? 'Click the icon to edit' : 'Click the icon to save'"
          :items="states"
          :readonly="!isEditing"
          :label="`State — ${isEditing ? 'Editable' : 'Readonly'}`"
          persistent-hint
          prepend-icon="mdi-city"
          :attach="'#attach'"
        >
          <template v-slot:append-outer>
            <div id="attach"></div>
            <v-slide-x-reverse-transition
              mode="out-in"
            >
              <v-icon
                :key="`icon-${isEditing}`"
                :color="isEditing ? 'success' : 'info'"
                @click="isEditing = !isEditing"
                v-text="isEditing ? 'mdi-check-outline' : 'mdi-circle-edit-outline'"
              ></v-icon>
            </v-slide-x-reverse-transition>
          </template>
        </v-autocomplete>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```